# No bearer token or refresh token being returned in response, CORS suspected - ServiceStack

Tags: cors, servicestack

In my development environment, everything works fine. Going to staging, however, now we have different domains and CORS issues for sure, which I have fully resolved expect for potentially one issue.

Regarding my CORS configuration for my APIs I am using the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors` Nuget package because I could not find a way to whitelist certain domains using ServiceStack CORS feature, and I read ServiceStack documentation... I now know that when I instantiate the ServiceStack feature there is an overload constructor:

```
CorsFeature(ICollection<string> allowOriginWhitelist, string allowedMethods = "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS", string allowedHeaders = "Content-Type", bool allowCredentials = false, string exposeHeaders = null, int? maxAge = null);
```

Anyways, so I am using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors`. With CORS correctly configured for my needs in my staging environment I am getting successful auth responses from my ServiceStack auth API like this:

```
{
  "UserId": "1",
  "SessionId": "V8wCKxOooCwLsQ1cn2jp",
  "DisplayName": "foo",
  "ReferrerUrl": "mydomain",
  "ResponseStatus": {}
}
```

And here is an actual response screenshot:
[image]

Just like this ServiceStack [user was experiencing](https://forums.servicestack.net/t/not-getting-bearertoken-in-ajax-response/4031). In this referenced link I see @mythz say this, "provider should be "credentials". This made me wonder if I had a CORS issue and because I am using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors` and not the ServiceStack CORS feature that `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` is false and ServiceStack code is checking this value and the bear token will not be returned. This is my configuration using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors`

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<DbSettings>(options => Configuration.GetSection("DbSettings").Bind(options));
        services.AddTransient<ITsoContext, TsoContext>();
        services.AddTransient<AuthService>();
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .SetIsOriginAllowed(CorsHelper.IsOriginAllowed)
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials());
        });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (EnvironmentHelper.IsDevelopment(env.EnvironmentName) || EnvironmentHelper.IsLocalhost(env.EnvironmentName))
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

        }

        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

        app.UseServiceStack(new AppHost(Configuration, env));
    }

}
```

So disable my CORS configuration in my AUTH API and instead used ServiceStack CORS like so in AppHost.Configure method:

```
var corsFeature = new CorsFeature("*", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS", "Content-Type", true);
Plugins.Add(corsFeature);
```

The last boolean parameter sets `allowCredentials` to true.

This results in HTTP OK responses which mean the credentials are good:
[image]

But we have Preflight Request CORS issue:
[image]

So when I whitelist my domains, set `allowCredentials` to true and add the `Authorization` allowedHeader:

```
Plugins.Add(new CorsFeature(allowOriginWhitelist: new[] {  "https://app.staging.mysite.com", "https://auth.staging.mysite.com" }, 
            allowedMethods: "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS",
            allowCredentials: true,
            allowedHeaders: "Authorization, Content-Type"));
```

We are back to square one so to speak, successful authentication, using ServiceStack configure CORS but still no RefreshToken or BearerToken included in the response:

[image]

After more thought actually and [reading this article](http://50linesofco.de/post/2017-03-06-cors-a-guided-tour), I am not so sure this is an API issue but perhaps this is a client CORS issue. I am using the ServiceStack Typescript client and mythz says right here credentials are included:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is missing the AuthFeature registration, but to enable JWT Tokens to be returned in Auth Responses you'd need to include `JwtAuthProvider` along with any other AuthProviders you would like to support.

By default JWT is configured with [RequireSecureConnection](http://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider#requiresecureconnection) where it only returns the JWT Token over secure (i.e. https://) connections, if you're not viewing this over `https://` during development or your going through a SSL terminating proxy you would need to allow JWT's over non-secure connections with:

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(), 
    new IAuthProvider[]
    {
        new JwtAuthProvider(AppSettings){ RequireSecureConnection = false },
    }
));
```

Otherwise JWT Tokens should be returned on "Authentication Requests" which are enabled when using ServiceStack's built-in AuthProviders, if you're using a Custom AuthProvider you may need to indicate that the Request performs Authentication by setting:

```
authService.Request.Items[Keywords.DidAuthenticate] = true;
```

#### Refresh Tokens

For [RefreshTokens to be populated](http://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider#requires-user-auth-repository-or-iusersessionsource) you'd need to be using an Auth Repository or your Auth Provider would need to implement `IUserSessionSource`.

#### Converting Authenticated Sessions to JWT

An alternative way of creating JWT Tokens is to [convert an existing Authenticated Session](http://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider#converting-an-existing-authenticated-session-into-a-jwt-token) by calling the `ConvertSessionToToken` Service or Ajax clients can call it by [sending a POST Request to /session-to-token](http://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider#ajax-clients).

Comment: Thanks @mythz for another prompt reply. Your answer makes sense though I am surprised about one part, during development localhost and also an HTTP development environment the refresh token and bearer token were always being returned in responses...I would think based on your answer that I would never had experienced the bearer token being in a response in my development environment if that all makes. Is my experience in my development environment because my auth api did not have the AuthFeature registered in the first place maybe?

Comment: @BrianOgden If the `AuthFeature` wan't registered you wouldn't be able to Authenticate at all, but if the `JwtAuthProvider` wasn't registered there wouldn't be any JWT Tokens created.

Comment: you know @mythz I probably have requiresSecureConnection set to false for local and development environment is what is going on, I do not have the code in front of me but I am guess that is what must be the case. And for my staging environment, I do have an SSL terminating NGINX proxy though I didn’t realize that was how I setup my first proxy till you worded it like that